# <img>'s used with address bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am trying to make a carousel for a header with images. I am using BOOTSTRAP 4 for the framework to make the carousel work

```
 <div id="aboutMe" class="carousel slide pt-1 container-fluid" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Carousel indicators --> 
       <ul class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#"></li>
          <li data-target="#"></li>
       </ul>
       <!-- slide --> 
         <div class="carousel-inner">
             <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506882741710-98761c574b48?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=794de1f3a10ddf74c928e6cebd1aa55e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80)" alt="The Chicago Theater">
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

what I am trying to do is make my image cover the container and as the container gets smaller or bigger the image resizes within the carousel

Comment: add bootstrap to your tags.

Comment: If you want to make your background image shrink with the container you can use the attribute `background-size: cover;` look here for more info: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the image as a background image with inline styling. You should add the image like this

```css
.carousel-item img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="aboutMe" class="carousel slide pt-1 container-fluid" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Carousel indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#aboutMe" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#aboutMe" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#aboutMe" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- slide -->
  <div class="carousel-inner active">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506882741710-98761c574b48?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=794de1f3a10ddf74c928e6cebd1aa55e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="The Chicago Theater">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506882741710-98761c574b48?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=794de1f3a10ddf74c928e6cebd1aa55e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="The Chicago Theater">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506882741710-98761c574b48?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=794de1f3a10ddf74c928e6cebd1aa55e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="The Chicago Theater">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#aboutMe" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#aboutMe" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: okay so I followed this code and it gave me what I wanted, but now when I try to resize the browsers the pictures tend to expand to a point where the image is not at a good quality, it stretches out and the image looks awful